# python without wing

Tags: python

Okay, I'm really new with python and in my class the prof assigned a homework where we fix codes without wing. I'm really confused because the prompt asks us to 'open a terminal window by clicking on the icon in the task bar that looks like a terminal screen. After it opens, it will display a prompt. Type the commands:

```
cd Desktop/cs141/11execution
python hello.py
```

So I understand what it is asking me to do and I think I opened the terminal window... but it gives me a syntax error. Can someone explain to me how to actually use python (how to open files without using wing.). I'm sorry if this sounds dumb but I'm extremely confused because i can't even open the file to get working on it.

I opened the terminal window and I typed in the command that the homework told me to do and it gave me this:

```
cd Desktop/cs141/11execution
File "<stdin>", line 1
cd Desktop/cs141/11execution
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: I know you are a new user here and I want to help, but you will need to give a little more info. What error are you seeing? And when you say "open" I think you mean "execute" the python script, correct?

Comment: Carefully read the first line of instructions you were given, and then **carefully** read the first line of output you gave.

Comment: This error might be misleading because you have done steps out of order. Right now you are in a python interpretor meaning you ran `python` first and then tried switching directories... Close your terminal, start over, and post the output

Comment: Oh. yes the first problem of the homework is to teach us how to execute a python program without using wing.

Comment: i closed and opened and it gave me the same output :[ @jdi

Comment: Are you opening a python interpreter or the command prompt window?

Comment: i'm not actually sure... it says at the top C:\Python27\python.exe and then on the actual screen it says : Python 2.7.2 (default, June 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32. is this right? or did i do something dumb again...

Comment: Ah thats your problem. You are running the python.exe executable, and not the shell prompt. Open the start menu, go to Run, type cmd, hit enter

Comment: I suspect you may have two terminal-like icons in you task bar, and that you are clicking on the wrong one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your actual homework assignment is to run and debug code without the help of an IDE, I figure I can at least give you details about the process leading up to that which is troubling you... And I can edit this answer to suit your updates.

When you open a terminal, you should see a command prompt waiting for input. This is a shell. Which shell you are in by default is system-dependent, but lets assume its "bash". Its probably bash if you see the prompt ending in "$"

When you are in a bash shell, you can issue commands. Python scripts start out by telling the system what type of interpreter it would need to be understood. Your script most likely starts with something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`, telling the system that the following text should be run using python.

**Make sure you are actually in the command prompt and NOT a python interpreter**

So once you have a terminal open, you first wanted to change to the directory where your python script is located. `cd /path/to/location` tells bash to change the current working directory. You would now be located in the spot where your python script exists.

When you run `python myscript.py`, you are explicitly telling python to run this script, regardless of what is at the top of the script with the `#!...`. At this point, your script should execute and the output would be related to the script.

In your example output, you have most likely entered a python interpreter, which is possibly by simply typing `python`. You can verify this if you end up seeing it waiting for input with `>>>`. At this point you have done something wrong. `cd` is not a valid python command. It is a shell command.

**Update**

You are now obviously in windows, so as I  mentioned in my main comment... Open the command prompt by going to Start Menu -> Run -> Type 'cmd' -> Hit Enter. Now continue following your directions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Notepad, type in `print 'Hello World'` and save as a Python file (`hello.py`). Place this file in the path `Desktop\cs141\11execution`
2. Press the Windows button, type `cmd`, press enter to open command prompt
3. Type the command `cd C:\Users\[Your_User_name]\Desktop\cs141\11execution` as mentioned in your homework
4. Type in `python hello.py`

If you get an error `python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` your environment variables aren't pointing right which can be tackeld easily enough. In step 4 just type `C:\Python27\python.exe hello.py` instead and it should work like a charm

This means that you've run a Python script through the command line. It's always taught to Python beginners because IDEs like Wing make people dependent and it's good to learn different ways to run Python scripts early on.

What you were trying to do was to use the Python interpreter (If you just typed `python` in the command prompt window) to run commands. This is different from running a *script*, since the interpreter allows you to test commands interactively.

Comment: I got an error after typing in the command : 'The system cannot find the path specified'. Does this mean i didn't put something in the rigth place?

Comment: Are you typing in the entire path? Say `C:\Users\[Your_User_name]\Desktop\cs141\11execution`

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows 7. For XP the path specification is different